# Corda flow has not showed up in jvm

Tags: corda

I am following the trader's demo, writing a similar one ([my project on Github](https://github.com/wuc6602fx/cordapp)) with same flows.

But when hitting "flow list" command in node's jvm, there is nothing like "Sellerflow". Please explain this.

[image]

Comment: I find the solution! Just because I have duplicate build.gradle files.

Comment: After I reorganize it, the flow is showed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate any flows that you want to start from the shell with the `@InitiatingFlow` annotation. Only these will show up here, because only these can be started directly.

Comment: Thank Joel. But I was already annotated `@InitiatingFlow` and `@StartableByRPC`on SellerFlow.

Comment: Is there something else might cause this problem?

Comment: Trying to build your linked project but I'm getting a circular dependency issue?

Comment: I just get one warning: **Warning:Kotlin: Classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\asus\Desktop\junit.jar**

Comment: I know circular dependency is bad design. But I am not sure whether it will cause error.

Comment: Can you please give me a screenshot that would help me find it.